# How to use language properties with Spring MVC 4 and jQuery I18N?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, internationalization, http-status-code-404

I'm developing a web app with Spring MVC 4 and jQuery I18N. I have already checked the following links without success:

[How to dynamically change language using jquery-i18n-properties and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637059/how-to-dynamically-change-language-using-jquery-i18n-properties-and-javascript)

[How to load i18n Property file using jQuery.i18n.properties.js + Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650773/how-to-load-i18n-property-file-using-jquery-i18n-properties-js-spring-3-mvc)

But when I access to the page, I'm getting **404 Not found error** in the developer's chrome console:

[image]

My project structure is:

[image]

In **cheque.js (Brown square in structure)** I have the following code:

```
function loadBundles(lang) {
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'messages', 
        path:'i18n/',
        mode:'both',
        language:lang,
        callback: function(){
            console.log(jQuery.i18n.prop('check_receiver'))
        }
    });
}
...
loadBundles('es');
...
```

1. In the red square is the file required to use jquery.i18n.
2. In the blue square I have the I18N properties files.
3. In the pink square are the files that contains the web page

In the **webmvc-config.xml** I have the following code:

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"
        mapping="/resources/**" />

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" p:defaultEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
        id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages"
        p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

    <!-- Store preferred language configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
    </bean>
```

Does the path in the javascript function is incorrect?

Is there any other file required by jQuery I18N?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just If someone is facing the same issue, after one week this is the answer:

1. Moved the properties files to the **src/main/resources** folder
2. Changed the **webmvc-config.xml** **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** code like this:

< bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" p:defaultEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    id="messageSource" p:basenames="messages"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

3. And finally the javascript function is like this:

   jQuery.i18n.properties({

   ```
   name:'messages', 
   path:'../resources/',
   mode:'both',
   language:lang,
   callback: function(){
       console.log(jQuery.i18n.prop('check_receiver'))
   }
   ```

   });

That was all folks!